# SQLite: UPDATE all rows/cols of all tables with the same (absolute) REPLACE function

Tags: sqlite, replace

How can all entries of all tables of a database be updated with - let's say - `n = REPLACE(n,"abc","xyz")`?
I don't know in advance, how many tables there are in the database and what are their names. Nor do I know how many columns there are in each table and what are their names.

Comment: Working on all entries of all tables in a database (independent of their semantics) is not a use case. This is either an  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem (in that case please explain what you want to achieve in this way) or it is a meta goal. I.e. you want to process a whole database for reasons outside of what the database is made for. In that case use the `.dump` feature, search-and-replace in the output (stored in a text file). Then create a new database with the desired change by simply reading the from an "empty" database.

Comment: If that does not satisfy you, then please create a [mre] in the shape of a few lines of `create table ...` and `insert ...`. Don't worry, the answer will not make assumptions on table names etc. The MRE is just to have something to demonstrate on. Make sure to include the desired outcome. To do that make a second [mre] of how the first MRE database should look like after the processing. Make sure to include some table names or other occurrences of the string outside of the actual entries.

Comment: "... or it is a meta goal. I.e. you want to process a whole database for reasons outside of what the database is made for." - Yes, that's it.     "In that case use the .dump feature, search-and-replace in the output (stored in a text file)." - Done.     "Then create a new database with the desired change by simply reading the from an 'empty' database." - reading the ? the text file I guess. How is this "reading from an 'empty' database done? In other words, what is the reverse operation of .dump?

Comment: Well, I found .read to be the reverse of .dump, but it is not needed. The final answer for me seems to be: `user@comp> sqlite3 db.sqlite .dump | sed 's|FROM|TO|g' | sqlite3 db-new.sqlite`

Answer (score 0):

After confirming that you do in fact want to create a new database which has a certain string replaced outside of semantic considerations, the method I already proposed in my first comment has been confirmed by you to be the solution for you.

With some additional details and explanation:

Use the .dump feature, search-and-replace in the output (stored in a text file). Then create a new database with the desired change by simply reading the from an "empty" database.

The empty database can be created with calling sqlite with a filename of a non-existing file. Feeding that call with a `.dump`ed file fills that new database with the changed input. The result of a `.dump` can of course be pipe-edited with `sed` as one way to do a search-and-replace.

I.e. , as you commented, `sqlite3 db.sqlite .dump | sed 's|FROM|TO|g' | sqlite3 db-new.sqlite` should work and seems to do the trick for you.

Comment: And now I need to find that other discussion I had on this surprisingly frequent use-case, to propose a duplicate there...